# C# UserControl multiple inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, user-controls

I would like to create my own user controls which implement more properties and methods than the ones given from .NET Framework. First of all I would like to have a custom `UserControl` class, which I would call `MyUserControl` and of course will inherit from `UserControl`:

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl {
   public MyUserControl() : base() {
   }
   ...
}
```

After that I would like to have my own `MyTestBox`, which will inherit from `TextBox`.

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox {
   public MyTextBox() : base() {
   }
   ...
}
```

My problem now is that I want `MyTextBox` to inherit from `MyUserControl` also, because I have properties and methods implemented there, that I need in `MyTextBox` also.

The only solution I could think of is to make MyTextBox inherit just from MyUserControl and not from TextBox, but add a TextBox in it in the constructor:

```
public class MyTextBox : MyUserControl {
   public MyTextBox() : base() {
      Add(new TextBox());
   }
   ...
}
```

but then I would have to re-implement every single property and method of `TextBox` in `MyTextBox`. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Make an interface with the properties you want, and use that as a mix-in.

Comment: That will not solve the re-implement problem, but it's what I thought off as well.

Comment: In case you want to extend the already existing Controls, you should create a CustomControl inheriting from the one you want to base. UserControl, IMO, are meant to be used for "new" controls, or Views.

Comment: This just can't work of course, .NET doesn't support MI.  And it is fundamentally fishy, a TextBox just is not a UserControl.  It is completely unclear why you don't use encapsulation, a UC having its own private MyTextBox field is boilerplate.  Just as you'd use MyTextBox on a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate out all the common code into a separate class and use delegation to handle it.

ie. something like this:

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    private MyExtraControlCode _Extras;

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        _Extras = new MyExtraControlCode(this);
    }

    public int GetInt32Value()
    {
        return _Extras.GetInt32Value();
    }
}

public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    private MyExtraControlCode _Extras;

    public MyTextBox()
    {
        _Extras = new MyExtraControlCode(this);
    }

    public int GetInt32Value()
    {
        return _Extras.GetInt32Value();
    }
}
```

or something similar.

Not as straightforward, but multiple inheritance is just not supported in .NET.

Comment: That's why, again IMO, in these cases you should use `CustomControl`

Comment: That is actually a solution. It gets a little messy though (extra Class, use of delegates)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the problem in more detail, I finally reached to this conclusion: There are 3 ways to achieve what I want, but all of them require some extra implementation.

First of all multiple inheritance is not supported in C# .NET. In my case it would make things more complex anyway, because in `MyTextBox` I wanted in a way to be able to access custom properties/methods from both `MyUserControl` and `TextBox`. But both of these classes inherit from Component Class, so multiple inheritance (if it were possible) would mess thing up here. The question I asked myself is: What do you finally want to do? The answer is, that I simply want to be able to "extend" all my `UserControls` (or `Components`) in general (namely regarding all `UserControls`) and also specifically (namely regarding `TextBox`, `Combobox`, `ListView`, etc), so that when I create a MyTextBox object, I could do both:

```
myTextBox.MyUserControlStuff();
```

and

```
myTextBox.TextBoxStuff();
```

So here are my solutions:

***1. Use extensions***

and extend UserControl (or Component) class. In that case, I have:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public void MyTextBoxStuff()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public static class UserControlExtensions
{
    public static void MyUserControlStuff(this UserControl control)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And MyTextBox can also do all UserControl stuff and TextBox stuff

**Downside**: every (specific) extension method applies to UserControl also.

***2. Use an interface***

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox, IUserControlStuff
{
    public void MyTextBoxStuff()
    {
        ...
    }
    public void MyUserControlStuff()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public interface IUserControlStuff
{
    public void MyUserControlStuff();
}
```

**Downside**: I will have to re-implement MyUserControlStuff each time again and again.

***3. Use an "extra code" class and make it a member of each custom UserControl & MyUserControl (like @Mr.Karlsen suggested)***

See the answer of @Mr.Karlsen for more details. I would say this is the best solution, but it has its downside

**Downside**: A little messy. A developer, new to my project would find it difficult to understand when seeing it for the first time. I would personally avoid it.

Finally I decided to go with the interface, because my UserControl properties/methods are specific to my needs so it wouldn't be good to extend UserControl with "specific" stuff. I have to write more code in my case and even re-write the same code while implementing my interface's methods, which I really hate. Anyway!!